# Set cookies for last five clicked links and get that cookies

Tags: php, cookies

If I have one webpage with multiple links like this

```
<a href="link_one">link one</a>
<a href="link_two">link two</a>
<a href="link_three">link three</a>
<a href="link_four">link four</a>
<a href="link_five">link five</a>
<a href="link_six">link six</a>
```

if user clicks this links i want to set cookies for only last five clicked links and and how to get that cookies using php

Comment: You are looking for sessions

Comment: you don't know how to set cookie in php OR you don't know how to read it OR you don't know how to keep five links in cookie?

Comment: i don't know how to set cookies for multiple links, could you give me some examples @Xlord27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u need to use jquery cookie.
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<div class="set-cookie">
    <a href="link_one">link one</a>
    <a href="link_two">link two</a>
    <a href="link_three">link three</a>
    <a href="link_four">link four</a>
    <a href="link_five">link five</a>
    <a href="link_six">link six</a>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var cookie = $.cookie('last_five_links');
        var links = null;
        if (typeof cookie == 'undefined')
            links = [];
        else
            links = cookie.split(',');


        $('.set-cookie a').click(function (e) {
            addLink($(this).attr('href'), links);
        });
    });

    function addLink(link, links) {
        if (links.length == 5) {
            links.shift();//remove the first link
        }
        links.push(link);
        $.cookie('last_five_links', links);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First set the code as..

```
function SetCookie(COOKIENAME,value,expiredays)
    {
        var exdate=new Date()
        exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays)
        document.cookie=COOKIENAME+ "=" +escape(value)+
        ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toGMTString())
    }
```

then give the links details

```
<a href="#" onClick="SetCookie('COOKIENAME','COOKIEVALUE','1')">
<a href="#" onClick="SetCookie('COOKIENAME','COOKIEVALUE','2')">
<a href="#" onClick="SetCookie('COOKIENAME','COOKIEVALUE','3')">
<a href="#" onClick="SetCookie('COOKIENAME','COOKIEVALUE','4')">
<a href="#" onClick="SetCookie('COOKIENAME','COOKIEVALUE','5')">
```

Comment: if i have thousands of links means what should i do, i need to set cookie for all the links for like this?.if user viewed some links how to get that last five links only? @KesaVan

Comment: Sure,if you want to get multiple links,you have to assign a link,you can use looping condition to get the correct link by giving link id...